# endless recyclerview along with load onscroll from server in recyclerview using cardview to load images and text

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll, android-cardview, swiperefreshlayout

I have implemented recyclerview using cardview to fetch images and text from my server using this tutorial:   http://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-listview-with-images-using-recyclerview-and-volley/.

I have successfully fetched the data and modified the code according to my requirement, now i want to implement swipe to refresh and endless scrolling similar to Instagram application. I have tried a lot of tutorials and SO questions however i am unable to implement any of them.

I am partially successfully implementing swipe-to-refresh but the app exits with an `inconsistency error` . kindly guide

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    // initially offset will be 0, later will be updated while parsing the json
    private int offSet = 0;

    private boolean loading = true;
    int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

//Creating a List of superheroes
private List<SuperHeroes> listSuperHeroes;

//Creating Views
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
public String Img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing Views
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //Initializing our superheroes list
    listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();


        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        swipeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                                 swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                 getData();
                             }
                         }
        );

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading) {
                        if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                            loading = false;
                            Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");


                            //Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data


                            loading = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }



    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData(){
        //Showing a progress dialog
        // final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);

// appending offset to url
        String url = Config.DATA_URL;
        String url1 = url + offSet;
        //Creating a json array request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url1,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Dismissing progress dialog
                        // loading.dismiss();

                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(response);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // stopping swipe refresh
                        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });



        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);


    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            SuperHeroes superHero = new SuperHeroes();
            CardAdapter car = new CardAdapter();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                Img =json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL);
                superHero.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
                superHero.setRank(json.getInt(Config.TAG_RANK));
                // superHero.setRealName(json.getString(Config.TAG_REAL_NAME));
                //superHero.setCreatedBy(json.getString(Config.TAG_CREATED_BY));
                //superHero.setFirstAppearance(json.getString(Config.TAG_FIRST_APPEARANCE));
                int rank = json.getInt("pid");

                // updating offset value to highest value
                if (rank >= offSet)
                    offSet = rank;

                //  ArrayList<String> powers = new ArrayList<String>();

                //JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_POWERS);

               /* for(int j = 0; j<jsonArray.length(); j++){
                    powers.add(((String) jsonArray.get(j))+"\n");
                }*/
                //superHero.setPowers(powers);
                Log.d("test",Img);
                car.setImageUrl(Img);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);

        }

        //Finally initializing our adapter
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, this);

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        listSuperHeroes.clear();
        getData();
    }

}
```

**CardAdapter.java**

```
/**
 * Created by Belal on 11/9/2015.
 */
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String imageUrl;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;
    String Load;
    static int count = 0;
    public static final String uu = "uu";
    String number;
 String  user1;
    public static final String UserNum = "UserNum";
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;


    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //testing from a real server:
    private static final String LIKE_URL = "myurl";

    //ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    //List of superHeroes
    List<SuperHeroes> superHeroes;



    public CardAdapter() {
    }

    public CardAdapter(List<SuperHeroes> superHeroes, Context context) {
        super();
        //Getting all the superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
        sharedPref  =context.getSharedPreferences(UserNum, 0);
        number =  sharedPref.getString(uu, "");


    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;


    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        SuperHeroes superHero = superHeroes.get(position);
       Log.d("position", String.valueOf(position));
        Log.d("url", superHero.getImageUrl());
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
        holder.textViewRank.setText(String.valueOf(superHero.getRank()));
        // holder.textViewRealName.setText(superHero.getRealName());
        //  holder.textViewCreatedBy.setText(superHero.getCreatedBy());
        // holder.textViewFirstAppearance.setText(superHero.getFirstAppearance());
        // Load =superHero.getImageUrl();
        // String powers = "";

        //  for(int i = 0; i<superHero.getPowers().size(); i++){
        //    powers+= superHero.getPowers().get(i);
        // }


        View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                count++;
                ViewHolder h = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                //   int p=h.getAdapterPosition();
                SuperHeroes s = superHeroes.get(position);
                //  Toast.makeText(context,s.getImageUrl(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Load = s.getImageUrl();
                Log.d("test", Load);
                String s1 = new Integer(count).toString();
                Log.d("count", s1);
                new LikeIt().execute();
            }
        };
        // holder.textViewPowers.setText(powers);
        holder.like.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return superHeroes.size();
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView imageView;

        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewRank;
        public TextView textViewRealName;
        public TextView textViewCreatedBy;
        public TextView textViewFirstAppearance;
        public TextView textViewPowers;
        public Button like;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewRank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
            // textViewRealName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRealName);
            // textViewCreatedBy= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreatedBy);
            // textViewFirstAppearance= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstAppearance);
            // textViewPowers= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPowers);
            like = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_like);

        }


    }

    class LikeIt extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag

             int success;

            String Imgurl = Load;
            Log.d("request!", number);

          //  try {
                // Building Parameters
                HashMap<String, String> Params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Params.put("Imgurl", Imgurl);
           Params.put("user", number);


                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script
               /* JSONObject json = jsonParser.performPostCall(LIKE_URL,Params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    //finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;*/
                String encodedStr = getEncodedData(Params);

                //Will be used if we want to read some data from server
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                //Connection Handling
                try {
                    //Converting address String to URL
                    URL url = new URL(LIKE_URL);
                    //Opening the connection (Not setting or using CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    //Post Method
                    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    //To enable inputting values using POST method
                    //(Basically, after this we can write the dataToSend to the body of POST method)
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                    //Writing dataToSend to outputstreamwriter
                    writer.write(encodedStr);
                    //Sending the data to the server - This much is enough to send data to server
                    //But to read the response of the server, you will have to implement the procedure below
                    writer.flush();

                    //Data Read Procedure - Basically reading the data comming line by line
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String line;
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Read till there is something available
                        sb.append(line + "\n");     //Reading and saving line by line - not all at once
                    }
                    line = sb.toString();           //Saving complete data received in string, you can do it differently

                    //Just check to the values received in Logcat
                    Log.i("custom_check","The values :");
                    Log.i("custom_check",line);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if(reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();     //Closing the
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Same return null, but if you want to return the read string (stored in line)
                //then change the parameters of AsyncTask and return that type, by converting
                //the string - to say JSON or user in your case
                return null;
            }

        }
    private String getEncodedData(Map<String,String> data) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String key : data.keySet()) {
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(sb.length()>0)
                sb.append("&");

            sb.append(key + "=" + value);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute() {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted

            }
        }
```

During swipe on refresh if i scroll down immediately after refresh the app crashes but if i wait till refresh happens i do not get the inconsistency error

Logcat error

```
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.tatson.bila, PID: 14987
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{278460a2 position=3 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:4247)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4378)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1161)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1018)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:3807)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-21 16:04:28.209 14987-14987/com.example.tatson.bila E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

also the load on scroll gets activated when i scroll to the end quickly and not when i am on the last item and scroll down

Thank You in advance!!! :)

Comment: checkout this great library : https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView

Comment: hi vipul, i have tried using this library but the same issue persists i cannot understand the logic of fetching data from the server side on swiperefresh and on load more. I dont know how the php should look pls help

Comment: am using recyclerview initially calling async task with page 1 with items count 10,set to adapter and then addonscrolllistener how can i call next call with page no 2 and how to add new data to existing adapterdata please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept behind Pagination :

1. You pass additional variable/value to backend(in your case PHP) let's say "last_seen". For initial fetching of values you will pass the `last_seen` value as 0, this means php will have a logic of getting values after this value upto some limit(eg. PHP will send the results to android from index 1 to 20).
2. And as you know your upper limit is 20, so next time at page load that is in `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` you will call the PHP again. But this time your `last_seen` will be 20 and PHP will provide you with results from 21 to 40, and so on.

The concept for Swipe-to-Refresh :

While Implementing Swipe-to-Refresh, it has a method named `onRefresh()` you will apply the initial PHP call here with `last_seen` as 0 and it will fetch the initial data from backend.

For Implementation go through following links :

1. [Endless RecyclerView OnScrollListener](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e)
2. http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/endless-recyclerview-onscrolllistener.html
3. [Basic Pagination Tutorial (PHP)](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination).

Comment: thanks alot for such a clean simple explanation as i mentioned earlier i have understood the concept however when i implement swipe the app crashes with inconsistency error, as shown in logcat and the onload sroll gets invoked when i scroll hard to the bottom not a normal slow scroll, being a novice pls forgive me for asking simple questions but it is imp for my interview project thanx

Comment: can you tell me on which line of code, this error is occurring.

Comment: i have no clue and hence my post on SO, i cannot understand why the code is giving error only on fast scrolling

Comment: the condition used in `onScrolled()` method seems wrong to me. I would suggest you to use [Endless RecyclerView](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e) for `EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener`. It is easy implementation of load more.

Comment: public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);  function in EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.java class gives me error where it is defined ?

Comment: have you checked the `SampleActivity.java` for its proper implementation. And `onLoadMore()` is an `abstract` method which need its definition while implementing it in `onScrollListener`.

Comment: ya i do it now can u help me with Loadmore function. iI mean what to implement over there in my case i want to load more 5 images from sever.

Comment: checkout easy to implement image loading library : [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: I have noticed that on 2G network the images shuffle while loading in recyclerview before displaying on their correct position while this does not happen on 3G network Why so?

Comment: bro im facing the same problem like you do and im almost solve it but there is some problem. can you share your code? so maybe i can solve my problem thx

Answer (score 2):

I also written a new blog post for the requirement you asked here.
Check this [Android Feed Example](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-feed-example-using-php-mysql-volley/).

You have to create a pagination script on your server. I used the following code.

```
<?php 

//Getting the page number which is to be displayed  
$page = $_GET['page'];  

//Initially we show the data from 1st row that means the 0th row 
$start = 0; 

//Limit is 3 that means we will show 3 items at once
$limit = 3; 

//Importing the database connection 
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Counting the total item available in the database 
$total = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id from feed "));

//We can go atmost to page number total/limit
$page_limit = $total/$limit; 

//If the page number is more than the limit we cannot show anything 
if($page<=$page_limit){

    //Calculating start for every given page number 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 

    //SQL query to fetch data of a range 
    $sql = "SELECT * from feed limit $start, $limit";

    //Getting result 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

    //Adding results to an array 
    $res = array(); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($res, array(
            "name"=>$row['name'],
            "publisher"=>$row['publisher'],
            "image"=>$row['image'])
            );
    }
    //Displaying the array in json format 
    echo json_encode($res);
}else{
        echo "over";
}
```

The rest is same.. additional I added a listener to load more records on the list after reaching the bottom of the list.