# How to implement load more recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement load more in Recyclerview.  Here is the code.
The code is from github. https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e

MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.tatson.bila;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.tatson.bila.CardAdapter;
import com.example.tatson.bila.Config;
import com.example.tatson.bila.SuperHeroes;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    // initially offset will be 0, later will be updated while parsing the json
    private int offSet = 0;

    private int previousTotal = 0;


    int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    int firstVisibleItem;
    private int current_page = 1;
    //Creating a List of superheroes
    private List<SuperHeroes> listSuperHeroes;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    public String Img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing Views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        //Initializing our superheroes list
        listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();


        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        swipeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                                 swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                 getData();
                             }
                         }
        );

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {

               Log.d("End","Sucess");

            }
        });

    }


    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData(){
        //Showing a progress dialog
        // final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);

// appending offset to url
        String url = Config.DATA_URL;
        String url1 = url + offSet;
        //Creating a json array request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url1,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Dismissing progress dialog
                        // loading.dismiss();

                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(response);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // stopping swipe refresh
                        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });



        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);


    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            SuperHeroes superHero = new SuperHeroes();
            CardAdapter car = new CardAdapter();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                Img =json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL);
                superHero.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
                superHero.setRank(json.getInt(Config.TAG_RANK));
                // superHero.setRealName(json.getString(Config.TAG_REAL_NAME));
                //superHero.setCreatedBy(json.getString(Config.TAG_CREATED_BY));
                //superHero.setFirstAppearance(json.getString(Config.TAG_FIRST_APPEARANCE));
                int rank = json.getInt("pid");

                // updating offset value to highest value
                if (rank >= offSet)
                    offSet = rank;

                //  ArrayList<String> powers = new ArrayList<String>();

                //JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_POWERS);

               /* for(int j = 0; j<jsonArray.length(); j++){
                    powers.add(((String) jsonArray.get(j))+"\n");
                }*/
                //superHero.setPowers(powers);
                Log.d("test",Img);
                car.setImageUrl(Img);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);

        }

        //Finally initializing our adapter
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, this);

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        listSuperHeroes.clear();

       refreshItems();
    }
    void refreshItems() {
        // Load items
        getData();

        // Load complete
        onItemsLoadComplete();
    }
    void onItemsLoadComplete() {
        // Update the adapter and notify data set changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Finally initializing our adapter
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, this);

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Stop refresh animation

    }
}
```

EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener class code:

```
 package com.example.tatson.bila;

/**
 * Created by Tatson on 23-11-2015.
 */
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

    private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    private int current_page = 1;

    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading ) {
            // End has been reached

            // Do something
            current_page++;
            Log.d("End", "Sucess");

            onLoadMore(current_page);

            loading = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: ok, so here is the code, and what is the problem?

Comment: recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {

               Log.d("End","Sucess");

            }
        });                                           i have called this in mainactivity however when i reach the end of the list i dont get any value in Log

Comment: Well, it *is* an interesting question because the listener with the endless name is a nice feature. But there are people who on the one hand might be able to help you and who on the other hand do not have a working sample in their pockets. Your chances of getting help from  them will increase if you post a minimal **code sample which does not depend on other resources** like server access(!) or custom java classes (SuperHeroes or CardAdapter...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842078/endless-recyclerview-along-with-load-onscroll-from-server-in-recyclerview-using/33864494#33864494     this is my original question .

Comment: Have you tried debugging the library? Whether the function is called or not is determined only by the boolean "loading". Just debug and see if the library is behaving as it should

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841740/how-to-know-whether-a-recyclerview-linearlayoutmanager-is-scrolled-to-top-or-b#) that, I believe, is much better than most I've seen on SO and elsewhere.

The idea is simple: in onScrolled in your RecyclerView's ScrollListener, check if the last completely visible item is the last item in your data set.

```
        if(llm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == data.length() -1){
            //bottom of list!
            loadMoreData();
        }
```

This happens with a method in the `LinearLayoutManager`. Calling `LinearLayoutManager#findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` can comparing it to the position of the last item in your dataset let's you know when you can load more.

I haven't tried this for the `GridLayoutManager`.

**UPDATE**

`LinearLayoutManager#findLastVisibleItemPosition()` is a better alternative to `LinearLayoutManager#findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`, especially when your items are longer than the window height.

Comment: But if i write my method in this ,for one scroll up it is calculating dy value and executing those many time.For instance if once I scroll up let dy value be 15 then this loadMoreData() method getting called for 15 times.Do you how to control it ?

Comment: @RushiAyyappa No I don't. Yes there's a lot of computing being done, but I'm yet to see this addressed as a problem. I'll keep my eyes open.

Comment: @RushiAyyappa  and wsgeorge Dont you thing onbindview will be better for this?

Comment: @PulahNandha If you mean the onBindViewHolder method, I could see how checking the item's position could be useful, but I'd rather the method focused on binding data to views, rather than knowing the state of the entire list.

Comment: @wsgeorge The reason why I am saying onScroll will call be called many more time then onBindViewHolder and hence if condition will be executed many times. I am not sure but I think it will impact on performance too.

Answer (score 18):

Check do you currently have items to scroll down -

```
if (! recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1))
```

If yes - load more items, for example, using HTTP client.

Full code:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (! recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)){ //1 for down
                    loadMore();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to this approach? It seems to be ridiculously simple, yet no-one else has mentioned this.

Comment: The disadvantage is that it only loads more items if you cannot scroll anymore - so the scrolling **stops**. It'd be better for the user if it already loads when there's only a few items left to scroll, since then the scrolling won't break.

Answer (score 7):

In **`Kotlin`** you can use the below code snippet.

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            if(!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                // LOAD MORE
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this....

```
  static boolean loadmore=true;
  LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
   recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            // super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisiblePosition == recyclerView.getChildCount()) {
                if (loadmore) {
                    loadmore = false;
                   method();
                }
            }
        }
    });


  private void method(){
      loadmore=true;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the accepted answer:

It's a better user experience if the scrolling doesn't stop before new data is loaded. Therefore you should load new data **before** the very last item is reached.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                // already load new data if there are only 2 items left to scroll
                if (llm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() >= dataList.size()-3 && !alreadyLoadedAllData) {
                    loadNewData();
                }
            }
        });
```

`llm` is your LinearLayoutManager and `alreadyLoadedAllData`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class LoadMoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
private LoadMoreListner loadMoreListner;
private boolean isLoading;
int vissibleThreshold = 5;

public LoadMoreAdapter(final LoadMoreListner loadMoreListner, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.loadMoreListner = loadMoreListner;
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int totalItemCOunt = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            int lastVissibleItemPOs = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if (!isLoading && totalItemCOunt<= lastVissibleItemPOs+vissibleThreshold){
                if (loadMoreListner!=null){
                    isLoading = true;
                    loadMoreListner.onLoadMore();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
public void setLoaded(){
    isLoading =false;
}
```

}

Your adapter will extends to this LoadmoreAdapter

```
public interface LoadMoreListner {
void onLoadMore();
```

}

And in your activity

```
@Override
public void onLoadMore() {
    items.add(null);
    nameLoadMoreAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size()-1);
    loadNewData();
}
```

After populating list and here your loadnewData() will have this

```
items.remove(items.size()-1);
            nameLoadMoreAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(items.size());
            items.addAll(itemsArrayList);
            nameLoadMoreAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size());
            nameLoadMoreAdapter.setLoaded();
```

where itemsArrayList are of newdata

Answer (score 1):

This links may help you .for load-moreRrecyclerview you need to change. and implement using 
[Link](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html)

or [library](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html)

Comment: in this tutorial he uses static data and i want to data from server.

Comment: setOnLoadMoreListener  in this method you can call again your webservices with use of limit of data 10 or what you want . its part of logic dear

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.support.v7.widget.OrientationHelper;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by CRAFT BOX on 9/7/2016.
 */
public class RecyclerViewPositionHelper {

    final RecyclerView recyclerView;
    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    RecyclerViewPositionHelper(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        this.layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    }

    public static RecyclerViewPositionHelper createHelper(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Recycler View is null");
        }
        return new RecyclerViewPositionHelper(recyclerView);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adapter item count.
     *
     * @return The total number on items in a layout manager
     */
    public int getItemCount() {
        return layoutManager == null ? 0 : layoutManager.getItemCount();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adapter position of the first visible view. This position does not include
     * adapter changes that were dispatched after the last layout pass.
     *
     * @return The adapter position of the first visible item or {@link RecyclerView#NO_POSITION} if
     * there aren't any visible items.
     */
    public int findFirstVisibleItemPosition() {
        final View child = findOneVisibleChild(0, layoutManager.getChildCount(), false, true);
        return child == null ? RecyclerView.NO_POSITION : recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adapter position of the first fully visible view. This position does not include
     * adapter changes that were dispatched after the last layout pass.
     *
     * @return The adapter position of the first fully visible item or
     * {@link RecyclerView#NO_POSITION} if there aren't any visible items.
     */
    public int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() {
        final View child = findOneVisibleChild(0, layoutManager.getChildCount(), true, false);
        return child == null ? RecyclerView.NO_POSITION : recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adapter position of the last visible view. This position does not include
     * adapter changes that were dispatched after the last layout pass.
     *
     * @return The adapter position of the last visible view or {@link RecyclerView#NO_POSITION} if
     * there aren't any visible items
     */
    public int findLastVisibleItemPosition() {
        final View child = findOneVisibleChild(layoutManager.getChildCount() - 1, -1, false, true);
        return child == null ? RecyclerView.NO_POSITION : recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adapter position of the last fully visible view. This position does not include
     * adapter changes that were dispatched after the last layout pass.
     *
     * @return The adapter position of the last fully visible view or
     * {@link RecyclerView#NO_POSITION} if there aren't any visible items.
     */
    public int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() {
        final View child = findOneVisibleChild(layoutManager.getChildCount() - 1, -1, true, false);
        return child == null ? RecyclerView.NO_POSITION : recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
    }

    View findOneVisibleChild(int fromIndex, int toIndex, boolean completelyVisible,
                             boolean acceptPartiallyVisible) {
        OrientationHelper helper;
        if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
            helper = OrientationHelper.createVerticalHelper(layoutManager);
        } else {
            helper = OrientationHelper.createHorizontalHelper(layoutManager);
        }

        final int start = helper.getStartAfterPadding();
        final int end = helper.getEndAfterPadding();
        final int next = toIndex > fromIndex ? 1 : -1;
        View partiallyVisible = null;
        for (int i = fromIndex; i != toIndex; i += next) {
            final View child = layoutManager.getChildAt(i);
            final int childStart = helper.getDecoratedStart(child);
            final int childEnd = helper.getDecoratedEnd(child);
            if (childStart < end && childEnd > start) {
                if (completelyVisible) {
                    if (childStart >= start && childEnd <= end) {
                        return child;
                    } else if (acceptPartiallyVisible && partiallyVisible == null) {
                        partiallyVisible = child;
                    }
                } else {
                    return child;
                }
            }
        }
        return partiallyVisible;
    }
}

/* NearbyModel */



/**
 * Created by CRAFT BOX on 8/23/2016.
 */
public class NearbyModel {

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(String rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getImage_path() {
        return image_path;
    }

    public void setImage_path(String image_path) {
        this.image_path = image_path;
    }

    String id;
    String name;
    String rate;

    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    String distance;


    public String getReview() {
        return review;
    }

    public void setReview(String review) {
        this.review = review;
    }

    String review;
    String address;

    public String getCategory_name() {
        return category_name;
    }

    public void setCategory_name(String category_name) {
        this.category_name = category_name;
    }

    String category_name;
    String image_path;
    public NearbyModel()
    {

    }
    public NearbyModel(String id,String name,String rate,String distance,String review,String address,String category_name,String image_path)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.rate=rate;
        this.distance=distance;
        this.review=review;
        this.address=address;
        this.category_name=category_name;
        this.image_path=image_path;
    }

}



 /* My activity */

 public class Search_by_shop extends Fragment {


    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<NearbyModel> near_data;
    NearAdapter adapter;

    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount,count=0;
    protected int m_PreviousTotalCount;
    RecyclerViewPositionHelper mRecyclerViewHelper;


     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_by_shop_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_by_recycleview);

        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                mRecyclerViewHelper = RecyclerViewPositionHelper.createHelper(recyclerView);
                visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mRecyclerViewHelper.getItemCount();
                firstVisibleItem = mRecyclerViewHelper.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (totalItemCount == 0 || adapter == null)
                    return;
                if (m_PreviousTotalCount == totalItemCount)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    boolean loadMore = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;
                    if (loadMore)
                    {
                        m_PreviousTotalCount = totalItemCount;
                        new GetAllrestaurant().execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        new GetAllrestaurant().execute();

        return rootView;
   }

   public class GetAllrestaurant extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        ProgressDialog pd;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pd.setTitle("Please Wait");
            pd.setMessage("Loading");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... strings) {
            UserFunction uf = new UserFunction();
            JSONObject json = uf.getAllrestaurunt();
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            super.onPostExecute(json);
            pd.dismiss();
            try {
                if (json.getInt("ack") == 1) {
                    JSONArray json_users = json.getJSONArray("result");
                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < json_users.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = json_users.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String distance = c.getString("distance");
                        String category = c.getString("serving_category");
                        String rate = c.getString("rate");
                        String address = c.getString("address");
                        String count_review = c.getString("count_review");
                        String image_path = c.getString("image_path");
                        NearbyModel da=new NearbyModel(id,name,rate,distance,count_review,address,category,image_path);
                        near_data.add(da);
                    }

                    if(count==0)
                    {
                        adapter = new NearAdapter(getActivity(), near_data);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    if(json_users.length()==0)
                    {
                        count=0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count+=json_users.length();
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("<-SubjectActException->", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class NearAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NearAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private ArrayList<NearbyModel> data;
        private Context context;
        public NearAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<NearbyModel> data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_near_by, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
            viewHolder.name.setText(data.get(i).getName());
            viewHolder.distince.setText(data.get(i).getDistance());
            viewHolder.review.setText(data.get(i).getReview());
            viewHolder.category.setText(data.get(i).getCategory_name());
            viewHolder.address.setText(data.get(i).getAddress());
            viewHolder.rat.setRating(Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).getRate()));
            viewHolder.vi_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    GlobalVariable.position=i;
                    Intent ik=new Intent(context,Restaurant_detail.class);
                    ik.putExtra("rid",""+data.get(i).getId());
                    startActivity(ik);
                }
            });
            if(data.get(i).getImage_path().equals(""))
            {
                Picasso.with(context).load("abc").placeholder(R.drawable.load_240).into(viewHolder.img);
            }
            else
            {
                Picasso.with(context).load(data.get(i).getImage_path()).placeholder(R.drawable.load_240).into(viewHolder.img);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            private TextView name,distince,review,category,address;
            private ImageView img;
            private RatingBar rat;
            CardView vi_click;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_near_by_name);
                distince = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_near_by_distince);
                review = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_near_by_review);
                category = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_near_by_category);
                address = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_near_by_address);
                img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_near_by_img);
                rat = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.list_near_by_ratbar);
                vi_click = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_near_card);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](https://androidreality.blogspot.in/2017/02/load-more-recyclerview-and-bottom.html) for Load More RecyclerView and Bottom ProgressBar.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a commonAdapter to handle loadMore

```
public abstract class CommonModelAdapter<T,V extends BaseModelViewHolder<T>> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<V>{

    public abstract V setViewHolder(ViewGroup parent);

    private Context mContext;
    private List<T> items;
    private List<T> copyItems;

    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_PROGRESS = 0;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    public CommonModelAdapter(Context mContext,List<T> items){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.items = items;
        copyItems = new ArrayList<>();
        copyItems.addAll(items);
    }

    @Override
    public V onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM){
            return setViewHolder(parent);
        }
        else{
            return (V) new ProgressViewHolder(parent ,R.layout.item_progress_loader);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(V holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ProgressViewHolder) {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).showProgressLoader();
        }
        else{
            try {
                holder.onBindData(items.get(position));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(items.get(position) == null)
            return VIEW_TYPE_PROGRESS;
        else
            return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    public T getItemAt(int position){
        return items.get(position);
    }

    public void setItems(List<T> newItems){
        this.items = newItems;
    }
}
```

> Where **BaseModelViewHolder**

```
public abstract class BaseModelViewHolder<T extends BaseModelBO> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public abstract void onBindData(T data);

    public BaseModelViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int layoutId) {
        super(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layoutId, parent, false));
    }

    public <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int resId) {
        return (T) itemView.findViewById(resId);
    }
}
```

**LoadMoreRecyclerView**

```
public class LoadMoreRecyclerView extends RecyclerView  {

    private boolean loading = true;
    int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    //WrapperLinearLayout is for handling crash in RecyclerView
    private WrapperLinearLayout mLayoutManager;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public LoadMoreRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public LoadMoreRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public LoadMoreRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        mLayoutManager = new WrapperLinearLayout(mContext,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        this.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        this.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        this.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(dx, dy);

        if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
        {
            visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading)
            {
                if ( (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount)
                {
                    loading = false;
                    Log.v("...", "Call Load More !");
                    if(onLoadMoreListener != null){
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    //Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(state);
    }

    public void enableLoadingMore(boolean moreLoading){
        loading = moreLoading;
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public void setScrolling(boolean enable){
        mLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(enable);
    }
}
```

**When you want to show progress...**

```
 mLoadMoreRecyclerView.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {

            {
                overAllItems.add(null); //to show ProgressDialog
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                callYourService();
            }
            /*else{
                //for reEnable calling it...
                mLoadMoreRecyclerView.enableLoadingMore(true);
            }*/

        }
    });
```