# Implement Load More in RecyclerView with PairList using MVP pattern

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, mvp

I'm looking for best practices. I want to implement load more [progressbar] after every 10 items (Using RecyclerView).
In past, I did this by simply creating *Loader* class item and just added into the specific position in my *List*. Well, this time, I'm using PairList and it's impossible to add Loader class item (even tho I personally think, that's a pretty clean way to do it).

I found a few solutions on SO, which are almost the same: [How to implement load more recyclerview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889955/how-to-implement-load-more-recyclerview-in-android)

Is there any other way I could implement this load more progressbar after every 10th element (First load 10 items from API, then, when user reaches 10th item, we show progress bar [meanwhile we fetch the next 10 items], remove progress bar, add 10 items and so on).

Answer (score 2):

Use this InfiniteScrollListener in your recycler scrollListener:

```
public abstract class InfiniteScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    if (dy > 0) {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int pastVisiblesItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
            loadMore();
        }
    }
}

protected abstract void loadMore();}
```

recyclerView Listener:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new InfiniteScrollListener() {
        @Override
        protected void loadMore() {
            boolean willLoad = //get your last api call data. if empty set false
            int offset = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
            if(willLoad){

                willLoad=false;
                onCallApi(offset,10);
            }

        }
    });
```

your api:

```
 private void onCallApi(int offset,int limit){
    //your api
}
```